# How to format cells inside DataGridView more effectively

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, cell, datasource

I'm writing ID3 tag editor and I have DataGridView there. I have ID3 frame IDs ("TIT1", "TIT2", etc) and I want to display corresponding labels instead of them ("Title 1", "Title 2", etc)...
So I used CellFormatting, but I notice that such event is called much more times than I really need and it makes my program slower. Is there a better way to implement that? I need formatting cells just when a new row is added to the DataGridView.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
                    if (known_frameIDs_current.Contains(e.Value))
                    {
                        e.Value = frameID_labels[Array.IndexOf(known_frameIDs_current,e.Value), isEnglish];
                    }
                    e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
```

Comment: The `DataGridView` has a `RowsAdded` event.

Comment: Don't get you; are you saying trhat you have eg a DGV showing a DataTable with rows that say eg TIT1 TIT2, and you want them to say "Title 1", "Title 2"? Use a dictionary and replace the values..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've rewritten the code using RowsAdded